# Setting multiple discrete groups in Drake

Tags: drake

We can *declare* multiple discrete state groups. But it does not seem possible to *set* multiple discrete state groups.

```
class DGEx(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        state_index = self.DeclareDiscreteState(5)
        self.DeclareStateOutputPort("group1", state_index)

        state_index = self.DeclareDiscreteState(9)
        self.DeclareStateOutputPort("group2", state_index)

        self.DeclarePeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent(
            period_sec=1e-2,  # One second timestep.
            offset_sec=0.0,  # The first event is at time zero.
            update=self.Update)  # Call the Update method defined below.

        self.DeclarePeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent(
            period_sec=1e-2,  # One second timestep.
            offset_sec=0.0,  # The first event is at time zero.
            update=self.Update2)  # Call the Update method defined below.


    def Update(self, context, discrete_state):
        discrete_state.get_mutable_vector().SetFromVector(np.zeros(5))


    def Update2(self, context, discrete_state):
        # the discrete state here is still from group1!
```

I cannot find a way to set the discrete state group 2. I cannot access it from any function argument. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to declare one `DeclarePeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent`, and the `discrete_state` that you get passed has all of the discrete state vectors inside it.  I would not think that your current call to `get_mutable_vector()` in the `Update` method would succeed (it should complain that you have multiple discrete states, so must pass the index).  You'll want something more like

```
class DGEx(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.group1_index = self.DeclareDiscreteState(5)
        self.DeclareStateOutputPort("group1", self.group1_index)

        self.group2_index = self.DeclareDiscreteState(9)
        self.DeclareStateOutputPort("group2", self.group2_index)

        self.DeclarePeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent(
            period_sec=1e-2,  # One second timestep.
            offset_sec=0.0,  # The first event is at time zero.
            update=self.Update)  # Call the Update method defined below.


    def Update(self, context, discrete_state):
        discrete_state.get_mutable_vector(self.group1_index).SetFromVector(np.zeros(5))
        discrete_state.get_mutable_vector(self.group2_index).SetFromVector(np.zeros(9))
```