# Is there a way to set multiple outputs from the same function while authoring a LeafSystem in drake?

Tags: drake

I am trying to output multiple vector results computed in a single function as different outputs ports of the same system.

I would like to do something like,

```py
class TestSplit(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort('port-1', BasicVector(1), self.SetOutputReference)
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort('port-2', BasicVector(1), self.SetOutputReference)

    def SetOutputReference(self, context, output):
        res1, res2 = foo()
        self.GetOutputPort("port-1").set_value(res1)
        self.GetOutputPort("port-2").set_value(res2)
```

However, it seems like this is currently not possible. I am aware that I could concatenate `res1, res2` and then use the `Demultiplexer` in the diagram to split the outputs, but I would like to know if there is a way to directly set it somehow.

Seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76027180/21652759

---

EDIT: The comments already answer the question. Adding another version of acheiving the same.

```py
class Option4(LeafSystem):
    """Provides two output ports from a single CalcSumDiff function.
    Option 4 uses caching so that CalcOutput reuses the tuple of values
    computed by the CalcAddSub helper function.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self._pair = self.DeclareVectorInputPort("pair", BasicVector(2))
        self._add_sub = self.DeclareCacheEntry(
            description="add_sub",
            value_producer=ValueProducer(
                allocate=lambda: AbstractValue.Make(tuple()),
                calc=self.CalcAddSub),
            prerequisites_of_calc={self._pair.ticket()})
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "add", BasicVector(1), partial(self.CalcOutput, port_index=0),
            prerequisites_of_calc={self._add_sub.ticket()})
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "sub", BasicVector(1), partial(self.CalcOutput, port_index=1),
            prerequisites_of_calc={self._add_sub.ticket()})

    def CalcAddSub(self, context, output):
        u = self.GetInputPort("pair").Eval(context)
        add = np.array([u[0] + u[1]])
        sub = np.array([u[0] - u[1]])
        output.set_value((add, sub))

    def CalcOutput(self, context, output, port_index):
        y0, y1 = self._add_sub.Eval(context)
        if port_index == 0:
            output.set_value(y0)
        if port_index == 1:
            output.set_value(y1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options.

The first option is the boring way -- compute the "single function" twice, and throw away half of its results for each output port.  It looks like this:

```py
class Option1(LeafSystem):
    """Provides two output ports from a single CalcSumDiff function.
    Option 1 does not use caching, so both ouput ports calculate both values
    each time and discard one of them.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self.DeclareVectorInputPort("pair", BasicVector(2))
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort("add", BasicVector(1), self.CalcAdd)
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort("sub", BasicVector(1), self.CalcSub)

    def CalcAddSub(self, context):
        u = self.GetInputPort("pair").Eval(context)
        add = np.array([u[0] + u[1]])
        sub = np.array([u[0] - u[1]])
        return (add, sub)

    def CalcAdd(self, context, output):
        y0, _ = self.CalcAddSub(context)
        output.set_value(y0)

    def CalcSub(self, context, output):
        _, y1 = self.CalcAddSub(context)
        output.set_value(y1)
```

The second option stores the intermediate result in cache entry, which allows the output ports to share the intermediate calculation, only computing it once each time the the input port changes:

```py
class Option2(LeafSystem):
    """Provides two output ports from a single CalcSumDiff function.
    Option 2 uses caching so that CalcAdd and CalcSub reuse the tuple of values
    computed by the CalcAddSub helper function.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self._pair = self.DeclareVectorInputPort("pair", BasicVector(2))
        self._add_sub = self.DeclareCacheEntry(
            description="add_sub",
            value_producer=ValueProducer(
                allocate=lambda: AbstractValue.Make(tuple()),
                calc=self.CalcAddSub),
            prerequisites_of_calc={self._pair.ticket()})
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "add", BasicVector(1), self.CalcAdd,
            prerequisites_of_calc={self._add_sub.ticket()})
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "sub", BasicVector(1), self.CalcSub,
            prerequisites_of_calc={self._add_sub.ticket()})

    def CalcAddSub(self, context, output):
        u = self.GetInputPort("pair").Eval(context)
        add = np.array([u[0] + u[1]])
        sub = np.array([u[0] - u[1]])
        output.set_value((add, sub))

    def CalcAdd(self, context, output):
        y0, _ = self._add_sub.Eval(context)
        output.set_value(y0)

    def CalcSub(self, context, output):
        _, y1 = self._add_sub.Eval(context)
        output.set_value(y1)
```

Here's another spelling that has fewer functions.

```py
class Option3(LeafSystem):
    """Provides three outputs from a single CalcOutput function.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self._input = self.DeclareVectorInputPort("input", BasicVector(2))
        self._cache = self.DeclareCacheEntry(
            description="cache",
            value_producer=ValueProducer(
                allocate=lambda: AbstractValue.Make(dict()),
                calc=lambda context, output: output.set_value(
                    self.CalcOutput(context))))
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "add", BasicVector(1),
            lambda context, output: output.set_value(
                self._cache.Eval(context)["add"]),
            prerequisites_of_calc={self._cache.ticket()})
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "sub", BasicVector(1),
            lambda context, output: output.set_value(
                self._cache.Eval(context)["sub"]),
            prerequisites_of_calc={self._cache.ticket()})
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "mul", BasicVector(1),
            lambda context, output: output.set_value(
                self._cache.Eval(context)["mul"]),
            prerequisites_of_calc={self._cache.ticket()})

    def CalcOutput(self, context):
        u = self.GetInputPort("input").Eval(context)
        return dict(
            add=np.array([u[0] + u[1]]),
            sub=np.array([u[0] - u[1]]),
            mul=np.array([u[0] * u[1]]),
        )
```

Comment: Thank you, the elaboration definitely made things clearer. Is no other way to set both y0 and y1 from the same output function? For example, when I compute a vector of size 3Nx1 within one function (say CalcAddSubMult) and want to provide output to 3 different output ports by indexing them somehow, i.e., for example `output['CalcAdd'].set_value` within one single port callback. I guess something like letting `class Option2(LeafSystem)` consume the `Demultiplexer`.

Comment: Ah, the specific complaint is the extra functions?  Well, I added Option 3 using a lambda to trade off the extra member functions for more constructor boilerplate.  There isn't any better sugar for this.  Possibly you could invent some and share it.

Comment: I could imagine using a [decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator) to flag calc functions (so not even the constructor has to mention them).  It could support multi-output-port calc functions directly (by doing all of the syntax of Option 3 under the hood).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation with multiple alternatives, Ive edited the question to add another `Option4`, I get the idea of it now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The approach for doing this is to [declare a "cache entry"](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_system_base.html#a7da4e8aa9a414faa5b40fc64e8ca40e3) in the Context.  Then whenever you evaluate either output port, it evaluates the cache (trigger the computation), and makes the output available.

The MultibodyPlant implementation uses this heavily. For a relatively simple example, you could look at the [JointStiffnessController implementation](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/6a8f832017bf62447c825eebbb6e11901f829c2a/systems/controllers/joint_stiffness_controller.cc#L62).